# Convert rows in columns

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a table in my MYSQL database: my table is a 3-dimensional matrix, namely:

```
FormId, FieldName, FieldValue
160,    TITLE,     A
160,    NAME,      B
160,    SURNAME,   C
161,    TITLE,     D
161,    NAME,      E
161,    SURNAME,   F
162,    TITLE,     G
162,    NAME,      H
162,    SURNAME,   I
```

How can I get this result?

```
FormId, Title, Name, Surname
160,    A,     B,    C
161,    D,     E,    F
162,    G,     H,    I
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using case when expression

```
select FormId, max(case when FieldName='Title' then FieldValue end) as Title,
max(case when FieldName='Name' then FieldValue end) as Name,
max(case when ieldName='Surname' then FieldValue end) as Surname
from tablename
group by FormId
```

Answer (score 0):

you can join three tables, and select one column from each table

```
select t1.FormId, t1.FieldValue Title, t2.FieldValue Name, t3.FieldValue Surname 
from tname t1 inner join tname t2 
on t1.FormId = t2.FormId 
inner join tname t3 
on t2.FormId = t3.FormId 
where t1.FieldName = TITLE 
and t2.FieldName = NAME 
and t3.FieldName = SURNAME
```